# Springboot @Component and @Autowired annotated, but still getting null pointer exception

Tags: components, inversion-of-control, autowired

I still could not figure it out why I am getting NPE at

```
foo.setName("FOOD")
```

Here is the code i am trying to run and facing the issue.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

@Autowired
private static Foo foo;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    foo.setName("FOOD");
}

}


@Component
class Foo {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Both `Foo and Application` classes are in the same package. The only way I got it working is by applying java configuration. So instead of

```
@Autowired
private static Foo foo;
```

I created the instance  using

```
@Bean
private static Foo getFoo(){
  return new Foo();
}
```

I tried to add @Componentscan to the configuration class but did not work. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is good to ask and it is also good to share my answer. Incase anyone came across the same confusion this might help. What i missed out was that bean need to be injected  at constructor of the `Application` class.

Modifying the code as follows did not cause null pointer exception.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    public Application(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    foo.setName("FOOD");
    System.out.println(foo.getName()); //FOOD ... console out put
}
}


@Component
class Foo {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```